# Using a button I want to add value to just one of the selected cells

Tags: vba

I have got a question.

I have made a button to select 3 cells. Now with a code I made it so that I can count -1 on the active cell and +1 to the selected cells. It works fine but, I want to add +1 to just one of the selected cells, the other I want to keep the value as it is.

Here is the code I've made so far

```
Sub AddNumber()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rngSel As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim Arr() As Variant
Set rngSel = ActiveCell
Set rngSel2 = Selection
Dim index As Integer
index = 0

For Each rng In rngSel2.Areas
    If index = 0 Then
    rng = rng - 2
 Else
    rng = rng - 0
End If

index = index - 2
    If RangerngSel = rng Then
    rng = rng + 0
End If

rng = rng - 0
    If rng.Count = 1 Then
    rng = rng + 1
Else
  Arr = rng
  rng.Value = Arr
End If
Next rng

End Sub
```

Is there a way to deselect the cell I dont want to change the value from?

A major thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to go about this would be to utilize the difference between selected cells and the active cell (within the selection range the single white cell among the other blue cells is the active cell). When a range is selected, the topmost, leftmost cell is the active cell. (Unless you select the range manually, in which case the first cell that is clicked on is the active cell.) And since you only want to affect 3 cells I believe it's simpler to avoid a for loop and the if statements that would otherwise be involved.

```
Sub AddNumber()

    'Select a range of 3 cells
    Range("C3:C5").Select

    'Subtract 1 from the top cell's value
    ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Value - 1

    'Activate the cell below the first and add 1 to its value
    Cells(ActiveCell.Row + 1, ActiveCell.Column).Activate
    ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Value + 1

    'Activate the third cell and add 2 to its value
    Cells(ActiveCell.Row + 1, ActiveCell.Column).Activate
    ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Value + 2

End Sub
```

Since you want to leave the value of one of the cells alone, you can omit one of the blocks of code, just adjust the `Cells(ActiveCell.Row + 1 [...]` portion accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I just now had time to try this out, it seems to work well, I only just need to close this 'loop' from repeating when clicked again if thats at aal possible, but for now, it works!

Comment: When you say stop it from repeating do you mean that once the macro has been run once, attempting to run it again should not work?

Comment: Yes exaclty, But I think in this case it would not be completely necessary since I will be the only one using the file.. But yes :)

Comment: @Sander For that you would need a persistent variable. There's no way to save values of dynamic variables strictly in VBA itself. You could either read/write from/to a file, or you could have a hidden worksheet and set a cell on that worksheet that stores a value. When you run the macro it would check the cell's value and make sure it's blank, then at the end of the Sub you would set the cell's value to 'true' or whatever you choose. You could also add a confirmation by wrapping the entire sub inside of `If MsgBox("Continue?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then [...] End If`